# How do I select an exact number of articles for each category?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here are my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `category` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `post_limit` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;

INSERT INTO `category` (`id`, `title`, `post_limit`) VALUES
(1, 'News', 2),
(2, 'Sport', 2),
(3, 'Science', 1),
(4, 'Games', 1);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `article` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `category_id` (`category_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=11 ;

INSERT INTO `article` (`id`, `title`, `category_id`) VALUES
(1, 'news article 1', 1),
(2, 'news article 2', 1),
(3, 'news article 3', 1),
(4, 'sports article 1', 2),
(5, 'sports article 2', 2),
(6, 'sports article 3', 2),
(7, 'Science article 1', 3),
(8, 'Science article 2', 3),
(9, 'games article 1', 4),
(10, 'games article 2', 4);
```

What I need to do is select 10 articles (`ORDER BY article.id DESC`) but bearing in mind that every category has `post_limit`, so for example we cannot take for `category_id=1` 5 posts if `post_limit=2`.

Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE 1:**
result should be:

```
10  games article 2     4
8   science article 2   3
6   sports article 3    2
5   sports article 2    2
3   news article 3      1
```

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired results?

Comment: Can we see what you've tried?

Comment: I will ASAP I get online, I'm on mobile now

Comment: @GordonLinoff - added update

Comment: @halfer - added update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to enumerate the articles to apply the `post_limit`.  You can do this with a subquery:

```
select a.*
from (select a.*,
             (@rn := if(@c = a.category_id, @rn + 1,
                        if(@c := a.category_id, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from articles a cross join
           (select @rn := 0, @c := -1) params
      order by category_id
     ) a join
     category c
     on c.id = a.category_id
where a.rn <= c.post_limit
limit 10;
```

In practice, you probably want an `order by` before the `limit` to have more control over which articles.  Similarly, you probably want another key on the `order by` in the subquery to control the articles . . . such as `order by category_id, id desc` to get the most recent articles.

Comment: Used your solution + added two changes to get exact result as I wanted: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/77033905/ss/2016-05-15_2146.png

Comment: Your solution is ok but there is one lack if one of categories has post_limit=0 or post_limit=NULL, then it should print all posts

Answer (score 2):

To limit the count of each category to the category's `post_limit`:

```
select c.id, c.title, least(post_limit, count(a.id))
from category c
left join article a on category_id = c.id
group by 1, 2 -- or "group by c.id, c.title" if you prefer the verbose style
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c4f739/2).

Answer (score 1):

```
select max(a.id) "Id", 
       max(a.title) "Title", 
       a.category_id "Category_Id, 
       max(c.id), 
       max(c.title), 
       count(*), 
       max(c.post_limit)
from article a 
left outer join article b on b.category_id = a.category_id AND b.id>=a.id
left outer join category c on a.category_id = c.id
group by a.id
having count(a.id) <= max(c.post_limit)
order by max(a.id) desc
limit 10
```

This will take each article ( table `a` ) and retrieve all articles in the same category with HIGHER Id values ( table `b` ).

Then you group by article id ( `a.id` ), and you only select groups having count LOWER than the category post_limit.